# Launcher intent behaves like back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have following logic when I resolve up `Intent`. Unfortunately calling this code (by clicking home button) makes it behave like a back press.

```
    if (parentIntent == null) {
        parentIntent = activity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(activity.getPackageName());
    }

    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(activity, parentIntent);
```

Following code does the job though:

```
    if (parentIntent == null) {
        activity.startActivity(
                activity.getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                activity.getPackageName())
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        activity.finish();
    } else {
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(activity, parentIntent);
    }
```

Anyone knows why `NavUtils` behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(Activity sourceActivity, Intent upIntent);
```

> Navigate from sourceActivity to the activity specified by upIntent, finishing sourceActivity in the process.

So yes, NavUtils.navigateUpTo behaves like a Back button press, and if you are calling the first piece of code from the Home button click listener, you will be taken back to the previous Activity.

Comment: Still from the documentation: "This method should be used when performing up navigation from within the same task as the destination. If up navigation should cross tasks in some cases, see shouldUpRecreateTask(Activity, Intent).". So probably the parentIntent is of a different task?